# Toggle button in Iphone Style

Tags: android, togglebutton

In android the `Toggle buttons` are looks like below -

[image: Android]

Can we modify this as `Iphone` style like below -

[image: Iphone]

And, Can we include the iphone functionality of toggle button like drag to toggle feature also.

How to complete this action? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That's not me, I would not downvote for such a question but I guess that's because you haven't wrote what you have tried so far, just waiting for a whole answer, maybe also because it is said in Android guidelines:Don't mimic UI elements from other platforms http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: Is there any jetpack compose implementation for this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just have to provide 2 drawables.

```
<ToggleButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_me"/>
```

and the drawable will be something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_me_on" /> <!-- checked -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_me_off" /> <!-- default/unchecked -->
</selector>
```

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't provide great transition effects, but will give you exactly what you asked.

Comment: I've already got this link, when posting my question here. Anyway, thanks for your link

Comment: Yeah sure. I'll. Do you know will this support for drag feature of toggle operation

Comment: That link leads to some fake scam website

Comment: Link removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 46):

Use `SwitchCompat`:

```
<!-- SwitchCompat -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_selector"
                app:track="@drawable/track_selector"/>


 <!-- thumb_selector.xml -->
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                <item android:state_checked="false">
                    <shape android:shape="oval">
                        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                        <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
                        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#0000ffff" />
                    </shape> <!-- shape circle -->
                </item>
            </selector>

 <!-- track_selector.x -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="36dp" android:height="20dp"/>
            <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
            <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="36dp" android:height="20dp"/>
            <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
            <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
        </shape>  
    </item>

</selector>
```

[image: toggle button screenshot]

Comment: @umerk44 It's in the source code of the answer

Answer (score 16):

If you want to do with shapes **(without using images)** try this. Currently im using it in a custom checkbox
[image]
[image]

```
<com.myapp.views.MyCheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/orange" />
```

checkbox_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_off" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_on" /> <!-- focused -->
    <!-- default -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_off" />
</selector>
```

toggle_button_off.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_background_off"></item>
    <item


        android:drawable="@drawable/white_toggle_icon"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="27.5dp"
        android:bottom="1.5dp"
        android:top="1.5dp"></item>
</layer-list>
```

toggle_button_on.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_background_on"></item>

    <item


        android:drawable="@drawable/white_toggle_icon"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:left="27.5dp"
        android:bottom="1.5dp"
        android:top="1.5dp"></item>
</layer-list>
```

toggle_background_off.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">


    <size android:height="32dp" android:width="60dp"/>
    <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="#919090"/>

    <corners android:radius="18dp" />

</shape>
```

toggle_background_on.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">


    <size android:height="32dp" android:width="60dp"/>
    <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/orange"/>

    <corners android:radius="18dp" />
</shape>
```

white_toggle_icon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
 <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
   <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#fff" />
   <size android:width="25dp" android:height="25dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: please explain how you customize **com.myapp.views.MyCheckBox** ?

Comment: this is a great answer, but the swipe doesn't work this way

Comment: @playmaker420  please post code of com.myapp.views.MyCheckBox

Comment: any way to scale these images with respect to height and width? I mean it looks good only for width 60dp and height 32dp.

Comment: This is achived using shapes and im not using images.May be u will have to play with the width and height

Answer (score 6):

Use of below code from [Android-Switch-Demo](https://github.com/pellucide/Android-Switch-Demo-pre-4.0) example. I can get desired output.

```
public MySwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    mTextPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Resources res = getResources();
    mTextPaint.density = res.getDisplayMetrics().density;
    mTextPaint.setShadowLayer(0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Color.BLACK);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.MySwitch, defStyle, 0);

    mThumbDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.MySwitch_thumb);
    mTrackDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.MySwitch_track);
    mTextOn = a.getText(R.styleable.MySwitch_textOn);
    mTextOff = a.getText(R.styleable.MySwitch_textOff);
    mTextOutsideTrack = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.MySwitch_textOutsideTrack, false);
    mTextOnThumb = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.MySwitch_textOnThumb, false);
    mThumbTextPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize( R.styleable.MySwitch_thumbTextPadding, 0);
    mTrackTextPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize( R.styleable.MySwitch_trackTextPadding, 0);
    mSwitchMinWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize( R.styleable.MySwitch_switchMinWidth, 0);
    mSwitchMinHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize( R.styleable.MySwitch_switchMinHeight, 0);
    mSwitchPadding =  a.getDimensionPixelSize( R.styleable.MySwitch_switchPadding, 0);

    mTrackDrawable.getPadding(mTrackPaddingRect) ;
    //Log.d(TAG, "mTrackPaddingRect=" + mTrackPaddingRect);
    mThumbDrawable.getPadding(mThumbPaddingRect);
    //Log.d(TAG, "mThumbPaddingRect=" + mTrackPaddingRect);


    int appearance = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MySwitch_switchTextAppearanceAttrib, 0);
    if (appearance != 0) {
        setSwitchTextAppearance(context, appearance);
    }
    a.recycle();

    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
    mTouchSlop = config.getScaledTouchSlop();
    mMinFlingVelocity = config.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();

    // Refresh display with current params
    refreshDrawableState();
    setChecked(isChecked());
    this.setClickable(true);
    //this.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```

Screenshot of the Application -

[image]

Comment: it so happens for some devices the swtch does not show the color(its grey for both on and off), and on some devices its size is really big. Any workaround ?

Comment: @TheUnknown No i haven't work around with that. Been working with iOS development.

Answer (score 4):

[image]
[image]

My `SwitchCompat` with `62dp` with and `26dp` height (base on @Thắng answer but I add 2 more TextView and 1 style)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_on_off"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyIOSSwitch"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb_selector"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:track="@drawable/switch_track_selector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switch_text_on"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:text="ON"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/switch_text_off"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switch_text_off"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:text="OFF"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/switch_text_on"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**switch_thumb_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="31dp" android:height="26dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <corners android:radius="26dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**switch_track_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="62dp" android:height="26dp" />
            <solid android:color="#F50000" />
            <corners android:radius="26dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="62dp" android:height="26dp" />
            <solid android:color="#888888" />
            <corners android:radius="26dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**themes.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...
    <!-- It helps change color when you press and slide on Switch -->
    <style name="MyIOSSwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
          <item name="colorControlActivated">#F50000</item>
          <item name="android:colorForeground">#888888</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You don't need to show/hide text ON/OFF because color of both `thumb` and `text` is white. If your text color is different, you can show/hide text by listen to `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on `SwitchCompat`

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using **com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial**

We can get a Good **transition** also

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
android:id="@+id/switch1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
android:text="Switch1:"
android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_selector"
app:track="@drawable/track_selector"
android:checked="true"
app:thumbTint="@color/white"
app:trackTintMode="multiply"
android:layout_marginStart="100dp" />
```

thumb_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#0000ffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#0000ffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>`
```

track_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="36dp" android:height="20dp"/>
        <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/primary"/>
        <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="36dp" android:height="20dp"/>
        <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

[image: Switch On]
[image: Switch Off]

Comment: Please be more specific or precise regarding your question. You could also insert your photos into your question. There is also option to resize the given images in your post (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405/3894304)

Comment: I am a starter. It's my first answer so It is not allowed me to insert Images. It says I need to get some points

Answer (score 0):

take all the images of off and on button and make a layout in relative layout like this

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/setting1"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/switchon"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="setting1Click" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/settingicon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/switchball" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/calsettingtxt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/settingicon"
                    android:text="@string/settingon"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

then in code when on is pressed make the background resource as off

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully we can use `materialswitch` from [MDC3](https://m3.material.io/components/switch).

```
  <com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image]