# When Toggled and disabled android switch is all greyed out

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image: Switch iOS]

[image: Switch Android]

As seen above when the switch toggle in iOS is disabled and toggled has color, but in the android doesnt.
Is possible to do the same effect in android?

Comment: There has to be a method to do that. Try `switch.setBackgroundColor();`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938315/toggle-button-in-iphone-style

Comment: @ Kapil G
I am using xamarin forms, that link is for android java.
@Robert Ruxandrescu
setBackgroundColor(); doesnt do what i want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to change the thumb color to match the iOS `UISwitch` track green color (`#41D150`), you can change the `colorSwitchThumbNormal` in the `Resources/values/style.xml` file (in your `Xamarin.Android` project):

Add:

```
<item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#41D150</item>
```

Forms running on `API 19` -  `API 26`:

[image]

> when the switch is disabled and is toggled, I want less opacity

If you want to change the `track` color, you can use a very simple renderer that changes all the Forms' `Switch` on Android:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Switch), typeof(StyleBasedSwitchRenderer))]
namespace Forms_PCL_XAML.Droid
{
    public class StyleBasedSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control?.SetTrackResource(Resource.Drawable.form_switch_track_mtrl_alpha);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Resource.Drawable.form_switch_track_mtrl_alpha` is a 9Patch image. the *normal* theme uses `abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png` in the AppCompat library.

So if you add a similar 9Patch but change the color:

[image]

You end up with:

[image]

Or use a drawable-based selector and two 9Patch images to maintain the same  default colors of the thumbs:

Renderer becomes:

```
Control?.SetTrackResource(Resource.Drawable.form_switch_selector);
```

Selector (`form_switch_selector.xml`) in the Resource.Drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/form_switch_track_selected" /> 
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/form_switch_track_mtrl_alpha" /> 
 </selector>
```

The two 9Patch files:

[image]
[image]

Results in:

[image]

Comment: What i want is: when the switch is disabled and is toggled, I want less opacity , not grey.

Comment: @Phill  `I want less opacity , not grey` ? Less opacity, so you want it lighter? i.e. a lighter shade of grey

Comment: Yes, I want ligther color, I want the same colors but with less opacity, on default in android, when is disabled turns to grey, i dont want that,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the default colours for the `Switch` control in Xamarin forms, you could use our `Effect` that we created in the Forms Community Toolkit...

The actual code can be use too if you want, it's available here

https://github.com/FormsCommunityToolkit/FormsCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/src/Effects/Effects.Android/Effects/Switch/SwitchChangeColor.cs

But best is to use it as done in our Samples app https://github.com/FormsCommunityToolkit/FormsCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/Samples/Samples/Samples/Views/EffectsSwitchChangeColorPage.xaml#L16

So what it does under the covers is hook into the actual Android native control and change the colours of it with the ones you provide in the XAML.
Native code for setting the colour is like this:

```
((SwitchCompat)Control).ThumbDrawable.SetColorFilter(...
```