# Switch control appears faded when not toggedon by default

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've got a bunch of databound switches on one of my forms:

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="option 1" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
<Switch Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" IsToggled="{Binding Options.One, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="option 2" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
<Switch Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" IsToggled="{Binding Options.Two, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="option 3" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
<Switch Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" IsToggled="{Binding Options.Three, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="option 4" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
<Switch Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" IsToggled="{Binding Options.Four, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Text="option 5" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
<Switch Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" IsToggled="{Binding Options.Five, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**Functionally**, this is working as expected. However, I'm seeing a bit of an oddity with the **UI**...

If the binding source provides "true" at the point the page is displayed, the switch control looks as I'd expect - nice and bright, no matter how many times I toggle it.

However, if the binding source provides "false", and you then toggle the switch to "on", then it looks faded - almost as if it's disabled, even though its fully usable.

As I say, the functionality behind this works - my bound properties are getting updated correctly - it's just the visual appearance that's bugging me :)

In this picture, all the bound properties for odd-numbered options was set to "true", whereas the bound properties for the even-numbered ones were set "false".
I've then toggled each option off and on a few times:
[image]

Comment: It has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/q/46157966/11104068

Comment: @Saamer I'm not sure it has? That question refers to switches that are togged and disabled. In my case, they are not disabled, nor toggled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7249) introduced in **XF 4.2.0**. To resolve it, you'll need to downgrade to something lower than **4.2.0** or upgrade to **Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.991210-pre2** (4.4.0 Pre Release 2) or higher where the [bug was fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.4/4.4.0#wednesday-november-13-2019---xamarinforms-440991210-pre2-440-pre-release-2).

If possible, my recommendation would be to upgrade to **XF 4.4.0** stable.

Comment: perfecto - much appreciated. Sad that my googlefoo failed to find that for me, but im glad it's not something stupid I was doing ^_^